# Is appgallery.cloud.huawei.com a Huawei site or kind of malware?

Tags: malware

I started to receive notifications urging to install the official Huawei app store, kind of alternative to Google Play Store. I would be glad, but the app immediately requires to give about all permissions that ever existed for the phone. Is it malware or just unprofessionally written? Please do not hurry to install the app if you just do not know.

One thing that made me suspicious is the app requires permissions right after start and refuses to do anything if not granted immediately. I would expect well written app to have some functionality available, and permissions box popping out only when the permission is really needed. At least could allow to browse over apps in the store - not any single permission is required for that.

Comment: have you ever been asked about Google Play permissions? is this more professional to you?

Comment: I assume you're using [a Huawei device](https://www.gsmarena.com/huawei_app_store_appgallery-news-30412.php)? Otherwise, it's strange to get such notification. Anyway, the SSL certificate for `https://appgallery.cloud.huawei.com` was applied by Huawei. Also, while the app requests so many permissions, the APK itself [looks safe](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/aa75742b139b93d58cc2288c42d340c577e182fc2ddcec8dc5bdac394514a89f/details) and it's the same as the one store on APK Mirror (verified by Android Police). Whether it's "unprofessionally written" or not, we can't answer it though...

Comment: Huawei device but I am not convinced the proposal comes from Huawei.

Comment: https://www.pocket-lint.com/phones/news/huawei/148102-what-does-huawei-s-google-ban-mean-for-your-huawei-or-honor-phone

Comment: @alecxs Google Play comes pre-installed so, indeed, I have never been asked.